# how to select max/min value into the same column in sql developer

Tags: sql, join, max, oracle-sqldeveloper, min

I have created one view(a7t3step1) with the columns OID(office id), HIGHEST(referring to max salary), and LOWEST(referring to min salary)(This information comes from employee table).

I am trying to create a second view(a7t3) that displays the columns EMPLOYEE_NAME, OFFICE_NAME, JOB_TITLE, and SALARY(This information comes from office and employee table).

For the SALARY column, I am supposed to select the LOWEST and HIGHEST salaries(should be 10 rows, one max/ min from each of the 5 offices) from the first view into the SALARY column(Not trying to concatenate them).

This is what I have so far, I do not know how to add LOWEST salary into the SALARY column of the second view. With the view I have created below, I can only see 5 rows(max salaries of each office). I have tried "inner join a7t3step1 on employee.salary = a7t3step1.lowest" after "inner join a7t3step1 on employee.salary = a7t3step1.highest" but then when i try to "select * from a7t3", I see 0 rows

create view a7t3 as

select fname || ' ' || lname as employee_name, officename as office_name, jobtitle as job_title, salary

from office inner join employee on office.oid = employee.oid inner join a7t3step1 on employee.salary = a7t3step1.highest

order by lname, fname;

Comment: It appears you have one employee with one salary, so the min and max are the same salary.  Can you us what you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

To get the min and max salaries for each office, you can just do the following query.

```
select o.oid, o.officename as office_name, min(e.salary) as min_salary, max(e.salary) as max_salary
FROM office o
join employee e on e.oid = o.oid
group by o.oid, o.officename
```

If you want to include it in your view above, use the query above to join to employee.  You cannot get the employee name from the same query that you are putting in your group by because you wouldn't get salaries by office.

```
select emp.fname || ' ' || emp.lname as employee_name, emp.jobtitle as job_title, 
off.office_name, off.min_salary || ' - ' || off.max_salary
from employee emp
join (select o.oid, o.officename as office_name, 
    min(e.salary) as min_salary, max(e.salary) as max_salary
    FROM office o
    join employee e on e.oid = o.oid
    group by o.oid, o.officename) off
on off.oid = emp.oid
```